# How can I prevent code from using wrong version of some dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project which depends on a JAR file. The version of this JAR changes often and we are having a hard time trying to ensure we are using the correct one. It is also causing problems when investigating bugs: which version of JAR contains the bug. Some programmers may forget to update corresponding dependencies and include 2 versions of this JAR inside the project, so that an old version may be found by the classloader.

A question is how to account for this issue.

I have a following plan:

1) When an error occurs log the JAR name I am working with to ensure it is a correct version. I plan to use something like

```
this.getClass().getResource(someResourceINeedFromThatJar).getFile()
```

2) I can write a test to account for this. But I don't know how I can run a test AFTER the package phase of my Maven build

3) Maybe you can suggest something else for this?

Comment: You are probably looking for [maven-enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/)

Answer (score 3):

Well, We have same scenario and solved issue by using maven **dependencyManagement**

It does two things.

1. Set a default version for dependencies in submodules/child projects
2. override the version of transitive dependencies

*it does override a specified value in a transitive dependency.*

The enforcer plugin does not ignore the **dependencyManagement**. But is unable to recognize the discrepancy since the **transitive dependency's** version was altered before it went to work.

Here is a nice article : You can go through it:
http://andydennie.com/2012/08/02/maven-enforcer-plugin-vs-dependencymanagement/

And another source: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/

Comment: Thanks a lot! But does this works for the artifacts which are NOT children of parent artifact? It is the problem we have. Is there a way to check that the build contains only one version of some dependency (or all of them) and print it ?